# How to handle FCM upstream message in Node server?

Tags: android, node.js, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using node-xcs module to create XMPP CCS server in NodeJs, But in that module there is no method to send ACK message which is required to send back to FCM.

Answer (score 1):

do you use fcm-node package for get FCM token . using that we can register device look at my full coding i have use it for send notification to mobile

```
var FCM = require('fcm-node');
exports.SendNotification = function(msg,title,type,id,user_id,api_token)
{

                        var fcm = new FCM(constants.serverKey);

                            var message = {
                                        registration_ids :  api_token,
                                      notification: {
                                        title: title,
                                        body:msg
                                        },
                                    data: {
                                        type: type,
                                                id:id,
                                                user_id:user_id
                                    }
                                };

                                fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
                                    if (err)
                                        {
                                        console.log("Error for Send Notification",err);
                                                return;
                                    }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        console.log("Successfully sent Notification", response);
                                                return;
                                        }
                                    });
}
```

and than call this function like this

```
msg='new notification for you'
title='Hello'
id='34'
user_id='34'
result='api_token'//save this token in database and retrive using user_id
SendNotification(msg,title,'START_APPOINTMENT',id,user_id,result);
```

Comment: For upstraem message we have to use xmpp ccs server, 'node-xcs' is module to handle that. I guess 'fcm-node' is not useful in this case.

Comment: @KrishnaAgrawal Many Thanks. Took me hours to find that module. It should be the answer. I haven't tried it yet tho. Is there any alternative?

Comment: @aung I couldn't find any better alternative for this. 'node-xcs' is working perfectly for me.

Comment: @KrishnaAgrawal Do you have any js client that can send upStream Message? Thanks

Comment: Upstream message is sent from Android device to server, do you want js client on Android to send upstream? If you want to receive upstreams on the server node-xcs works great.

Comment: On NPM there is now a comment on fcm-node Warning: on February 2, 2017, the Firebase Team released the admin.messaging() service to their node.js admin module. This new service makes this module kind of deprecated